# Word table with borders

Tags: c#, automation, ms-word, ms-office

The following code inserts a table to the Word document:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
...
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

Word.Table oTable;
Word.Range wrdRng = oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(wrdRng, 3, 5, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;
int r, c;
string strText;
for (r = 1; r <= 3; r++)
    for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
    {
        strText = "r" + r + "c" + c;
        oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = strText;
    }
```

This code is from the article: http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;316384&spid=2530&sid=47

Result is:

```
r1c1    r1c2    r1c3    r1c4    r1c5
r2c1    r2c2    r2c3    r2c4    r2c5
r3c1    r3c2    r3c3    r3c4    r3c5
```

Resulting table doesn't have borders. How can I change this code to get a table with borders, like in "Insert Table" Word command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderRight].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderTop].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].LineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
```

Put in cycle.

Also you can set line width and color:

```
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].LineWidth = WdLineWidth.wdLineWidth050pt;
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].Color = WdColor.wdColorRed;
```

Answer (score 11):

I used the following options to set all borders and it is quite easier than settings borders for every cell. Please note that the logic for getting `Range rng` is for VSTO add-in, but the table logic remains same.

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    ......
    void AddTable()
    {
      Range rng = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
      Table tbl = rng.Tables.Add(rng, 3, 5); //make table at current selection
      tbl.Range.Font.Name = "Calibri";
      tbl.Range.Font.Size = 10.5F;
      tbl.Range.Font.Bold = 0;

      //these 2 lines put borders both inside & outside - see result image at end
      tbl.Borders.InsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
      tbl.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;

      for (r = 1; r <= 3; r++)
        for (c = 1; c <= 5; c++)
        {
          strText = "r" + r + "c" + c;
          oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = strText;
        }

    }
```

Result will be like table below with borders

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this commands:

```
oTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle; 
oTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleDouble;
```

Use them in cycle. After putting the text.

Comment: Thanks. This code, both if added to the loop or before/after the loop, creates horizontal and external vertical lines. Internal vertical lines are still missing.