# How do I draw a border on a series of cells using Interop.Word?

Tags: c#, word-interop

I am currently using Interop.Word to draw tables for a document.
I am looking to draw only the outside border for a set of cells (e.g. R1C1 to R2C3)
I roughly know how to draw a full outside border around one cell.

Any advice is appreciated.

I know I can set the border for a cell by calling the outsidelinestyle code.

I've read somewhere I can manually call the individual borders but that would be my worst case scenario. 
[Word table with borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808928/word-table-with-borders)

Currently what I have for those 1x1 cells is this:

```
    Word.Cell wrdCell = wdTable.Cell(1, 1);
    wrdCell.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
```

I am hoping that I can just call something to draw the border around the range of cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Try to rework below code :

```
Word.Range range = w_doc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);
Word.Table myTable = range.Tables.Add(range, numero_de_linhas, numero_de_colunas);

myTable.Borders.InsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
myTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
```

Comment: there does not seem to be a mapping to the BorderAround2 function or the get_Range function for Tables in word. I might be missing something though while checking intellisense.

Comment: I've tried this and I think it is similar to the answer I have attached to my question. It work for the outside and internal borders, but it does not help when I want to only apply the outside border over a range of cells.

Comment: Well its not like Your question since You are working on single cell, here I'm using range which is slightly different.. Range in word points on quantity not on position in table, check this out  : 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-define-and-select-ranges-in-documents?view=vs-2019